# What is a "single side debit: QMC charges" in bank transactions?

Tags: banking, india, fees

My bank account is debited with description single side debit QMC charges.

For what purpose the single side debit is charged.

BANK NAME: CITY UNION BANK

COUNTRY: INDIA

Comment: Go through this document http://www.google.co.uk/url?q=http://cityunionbank.com/PageMenuDocs/service_charges.pdf&sa=U&ei=nEILU_SyLImv7AbZ0YGwCg&ved=0CB4QFjAA&sig2=O7_hcCJF6ZASN_oPbdidnw&usg=AFQjCNFvi-WmF1OaGTFJbAJqPmkCcggc2w

Answer (score 1):

What country and Bank? It could be a specific narration used by a Bank to indicate that the charges are as a result QMC [Quarterly Maintenance Charges?] rather than any payment instructions ...

Comment: Note edits in my question

Answer (score -2):

QMC Charges means Quarterly Minimum Charges... Why because bank persons can directly debit these charges for Not maintaining of Minimum balance on Quarterly base...